# Java startsWith dont work properly

Tags: java, string, netbeans

I got a table of two strings:

```
String[] tab = {"why","Why"};
```

And I want to it them to see if somebody is asking a question with different words than those in my tab[]:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            if(!message.startsWith(tab[i])){
                System.out.println("Ask using why or Why");
                break;      
            }
            }
```

When I'm typing my input: "Why the weather is bad?", it returns: "Ask using why or Why".
Also when I type: "How are you?", it return "Ask using why or Why".

I want this program to allow only question that starts with why or Why.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to "it" them?

Comment: What is the contents of `message`?  Please post the code used to populate `message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing:

1. Match against the first entry
2. If it doesn't match, show the message to the user and abort.

What you wanted to do:

1. Match against the first entry.
2. If it doesn't match, try the next entry.
3. If no entries matched, show a message to the user and abort.

Here's an example:

```
boolean found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    if(message.startsWith(tab[i])){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Ask using why or Why");
}
```

In your particular instance, you can also just check the lowercase version of the string:

```
if (!message.toLowerCase().startsWith("why")) {
    System.out.println("Ask using why or Why");
}
```